# php command that returns entire url including get action

Tags: php

How do I return the entire url of a page including get.

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and php_self doesn't do it.

they return www.domain.com/example
instead of www.domain.com/example?user=2

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER) will help in the future when searching for this type of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

If you don't wish to return the domain, but just the internal url and get variables you can omit $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].

Answer (score 1):

One other thing, `$_SERVER` is an array, so are `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE`

So if you're not sure if the data is contained within those variables, then try something like this.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

[`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) contains the requested URL path and query.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is probably what you are looking for, just remember that you will need to encode it if you wish to send that in a "GET".